# Wordpress BB press Css Issue

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I only have one issue regarding the css, I have thesis theme installed and the buttons are dis aligned you can see it here http://www.simplestepstowellness.com/forums/forum/dexters-forum-about-wordpress/ the submit button and notify checkbox are dis aligned I don't know where to edit such css for this or which file does it located. Please help, would be so much appreciated.

Thanks and God Bless,
Dex

Answer (score 0):

Log on to wordpress 'URL/wp-admin', Click Appearance down the right panel, then click editor the default file that pops up will be the CSS file you will then have to find the specific element and style it.

Comment: Just Figure things out, I've edited the main core function of the bbpress theme and it is where the files are located. Thanks for your answer. it is not shown in dashboard editor. You need to edit it via ftp access. Thanks

Comment: Thats potentially a permissions thing then, if you had full access you would be able to edit core css, html and js from the wordpress admin section. The only thing you will need to access the FTP for is editing the PHP and javascript plugins I think, glad you sorted it out !